# How to stay logged into Magento 2.0 longer

Tags: magento2, login, session, magento-2.0.2, logout

Magento 2.0.2 seems to log me out after 5 or so minutes of inactivity.

Is there a setting to keep me logged into the Admin backend longer? If so, where and how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to *Stores > Config > Advanced > Admin > Security* and edit the *Admin Session Lifetime* field. This is in seconds, for development purposes I usually go for **28800** which is **8 hours**.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @Ben-Space48. Of course, I was looking in the System area. "Stores" was way too un-intuitive for me. I'll get there though....

Comment: Yeah it isn't very clear I'm not even sure how I found it, glad to help!